# Bounded $p$-norm but unbounded $q$-norm for any $p < q$

Tags: normed-spaces, lp-spaces

This question has bothered me for a while, and I hope to have it clarified if possible.

Consider a set of functions $G:=\{ g : (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+ \;|\; (\int_0^1 g(t)^p dt)^{1/p} \leq k \text{ and} \int_0^1g(t)dt=1\}$ for some $k\geq 1$

> Is it always possible to find a $g^* \in G$ such that $||g^*||_q=\infty$ where $q>p\geq 1$ or not?

I am not sure if this should be something obvious or not. Does this depend on $k$? If so, any way to understand the dependency?

Answer (score 4):

Let $r$ satisfy $p<r<q$. Set $s=1-\frac{p}{r}$.  Note that $0<s<1$.  Set $g(t)=s^{1/p}t^{-1/r}$.  Now, $$\int_0^1 g(t)^pdt=\int_0^1 st^{-p/r}dt= t^s|_0^1=1$$

Now set $u=1-\frac{q}{r}$, and note that $u<0$.
$$\int_0^1 g(t)^qdt=s^{q/p}\int_0^1t^{-q/r}dt=\frac{s^{q/p}}{u}t^u|_0^1=\infty$$

Comment: It was such an elegant example. I have been trying so hard without the success. Would you mind share some tips about how you identify such an example?

Comment: The key part is that we want to integrate a power of $t$, where the result is either a positive power of $t$, or a negative power of $t$.  Everything else is details to make this work out.

Comment: right, that's the perspective to take. thanks a lot, learn more than I would expect.